# How to find files ending with a specific string in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

In IntelliJ, you can list files using the `Navigate > File...` option (keyboard shortcut `Ctrl+Shift+N`). Using this feature, if I try to search for Java files ending with `IT` (which are integration tests), searching for `*IT.java` will return `IterableTransformer.java` for example, which is obviously not what I want.

So my question is, I can I do that in IntelliJ?

Comment: You can try using the [Scopes feature](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-scopes.html) and define a custom scope for the integration tests to view in the Project tool window.

Comment: I could try that, sure. But that still doesn't tell me how to search for files that end with a specific string. I am sure there is a way to do something that simple?

Comment: Names ending with `IT.java` are supposed to be on top of the list for such a query. Could you please provide an example file name that doesn't behave so? Does `Navigate > File` show that file for other queries (e.g. its full name)?

Comment: @PeterGromov thank you! It was just that! I did not have any `IT.java` files! Silly me... :P ... and I approved your answer.

Comment: Oh wait, I just tried with another colleague. And surprisingly, when we enter `*IT.java`, files ending with `IT.java` don't appear on top. Or at least, not at the very top. There are 5 files that meet that criteria, and they appear in the top 10. But the top file was actually something like `IterableListTransformer.java`. Weird. I think implementation code is prioritized over test code.

Comment: Implementation isn't prioritized over tests. I'd appreciate if you filed an issue at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com with a screenshot of what you get that includes both `*IT` files and the topmost shown suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Find in Path` functionality as a workaround: enter an empty search string there, and `*IT.java` in "file mask" field.